Regex doesn't match subgroups as expected
I am writing a C program that makes use of regex to detect a string like:
hl # # #
Where # indicates an integer.  Up to 11 integer values should be captured here
I have written the following regular expression to satisfy this, (and below that, I provided a sample value) :
#define HARDLINK_MATCH_EXPRESSION "^hl( ([1-9][0-9]*))*( ([1-9][0-9]*))*( ([1-9][0-9]*))*( ([1-9][0-9]*))*( ([1-9][0-9]*))*( ([1-9][0-9]*))*( ([1-9][0-9]*))*( ([1-9][0-9]*))*( ([1-9][0-9]*))*( ([1-9][0-9]*))*( ([1-9][0-9]*))*"
char *sampleValue = "hl 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11" ;

However, in both the C program and at https://regex101.com/ I find that the string matches, but only one integer (the last one) is "captured."  My thinking is that this defines a series of eleven greedy "outer" groups, and I expected that each group would be satisfied by this example.
I have pored through uncounted solutions to this sort of problem, and though I'm certain my question is probably not unique, I couldn't find a match in the multitude of answers.
Can someone explain why the expression does not capture the inner groups as well as the final (until the expression runs out at 11 captures) ??
EDIT
While I still would like the first question answered, my real question is whether there is a way to capture all of the groups in the sample.
Thanks.

Repeating a capture group will capture the value of the last repetition.

Thanks, I asked the wrong question @Thefourthbird

There are regex engines like .NET and PyPi for Python that have a captures collection to get all the group values, not sure if C has library for that.

Which regex library are you using?  That is key information — the answers for POSIX <regex.h>
are going to be different from those for PCRE2.  There are other regex libraries out there for use in C.  Please remember to identify which species of regex you are working with.

The hl( ([1-9][0-9]*))* portion of your pattern matches the entire string. The rest of the pattern just matches empty strings. So you have two captures that match something other than an empty string.
Changing each ( ([1-9][0-9]*))* to ( ([1-9][0-9]*))? would solve the problem. However, I would write the pattern as follows:
^
hl
(?:
   [ ] (0|[1-9][0-9]*)
   (?:
      [ ] (0|[1-9][0-9]*)
      (?:
         [ ] (0|[1-9][0-9]*)
         (?:
            [ ] (0|[1-9][0-9]*)
            (?:
               [ ] (0|[1-9][0-9]*)
               (?:
                  [ ] (0|[1-9][0-9]*)
                  (?:
                     [ ] (0|[1-9][0-9]*)
                     (?:
                        [ ] (0|[1-9][0-9]*)
                        (?:
                           [ ] (0|[1-9][0-9]*)
                           (?:
                              [ ] (0|[1-9][0-9]*)
                              (?:
                                 [ ] (0|[1-9][0-9]*)
                              )?
                           )?
                        )?
                     )?
                  )?
               )?
            )?
         )?
      )?
   )?
)?

I wrote it as if whitespace is allowed (as per the x flag in some engines) for readability. If you don't have that luxury, it compresses into the following:
^hl(?: (0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?: (0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?: (0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?: (0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?: (0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?: (0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?: (0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?: (0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?: (0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?: (0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?: (0|[1-9][0-9]*))?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?

Notes:

I removed the extra captures. You had twice as many as desired.
Using (?: [ ] (0|[1-9][0-9]*) (?: ... )? )? instead of (?: [ ] (0|[1-9][0-9]*) )? (?: ... )? makes more sense, and it can greatly reduce backtracking on a failed match.
I changed the pattern to allow a 0. Replace 0|[1-9][0-9]* with [1-9][0-9]* to continue disallowing it.


Brilliant!  Thanks so much!  I will put it into the prograsm as you've written it, then pull out the newlines and their whitspaces via code - the way you have written it makes it crystal (and not prone to typos etc).  This is high quality!

Careful not to remove the space you want to keep. You might be able to use \h (or even \h+), \s (or even \s+) or \x20 instead of [ ] to sidestep that issue. Your engine may or may not support these, or it may use a different syntax. Careful, though. \h matches any horizontal whitespace character (so it includes tabs and others), and \s matches any whitespace character (so it includes tabs, line feeds and others). And don't forget to escape the \  in the string literal.

Thanks, yes.  I am writing a function to remove newline and any whitespace after it, until not whitespace.  It'll be fine.  (Though I think I will adopt the \x20 plan.  Was thinking of that anyway.

Your test expresssion is matched by this part of your regex alone: ^hl( ([1-9][0-9]*))*.  That leaves nothing for the other capturing groups to match or capture, which is fine as far as the given regex is concerned.  You therefore end with only groups 1 and 2 capturing anything.
Furthermore, when, through the use of quantification, a capturing group in a regex matches the input multiple times, only the last match is captured.  Therefore, in this case, group 1 will capture " 11", and group 2 will capture "11".
Possibly you are using the wrong quantifier.  * will cause the group so quantified to match an unbounded number of times, but ? will cause it to match at most once (in most regex dialects; you didn't say which you are using).  Thus, this may be more what you were after:
#define HARDLINK_MATCH_EXPRESSION "^hl( ([1-9][0-9]*))?( ([1-9][0-9]*))?( ([1-9][0-9]*))?( ([1-9][0-9]*))?( ([1-9][0-9]*))?( ([1-9][0-9]*))?( ([1-9][0-9]*))?( ([1-9][0-9]*))?( ([1-9][0-9]*))?( ([1-9][0-9]*))?( ([1-9][0-9]*))?"


That does solve the issue, but it has twice as many captures as necessary, it can perform really poorly if the line doesn't match, and it doesn't accept 0 (which may or may not be intentional).

@ikegami, the alternative presented here matches exactly the same strings as the OP's, no more and no less, up to the limit on number of captures they wanted. It structures the captures as the OP's does, which might or might not be what they want, but it's what they asked about.  And it might or might not be more captures than necessary.  Not all regex dialects recognize non-capturing groups.

Re "It structures the captures as the OP's does", Not at all. The question is about capturing the correct things. You changed the structure of the captures, but possibly not enough. While it's not definitely wrong to have extra captures, and it's something that can be worked around, it's likely wrong. I was just pointing that out. /// Not accepting 0 is also only likely wrong. I was just pointing that out. /// There's no reason for the excessive backtracking, though.
